# Appending a Google Sheet file with newest Google Drive .csv file located in a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, zapier

I've got a plugin that works with Zapier to send a .csv (can have different format) file to a specific Google Drive folder with some order data from the day before, every 24h.

I would love to append my Google Sheet file using AppsScript with the data from the newest file in the folder.

Is such solution even possible? What sources would you recommend to try to write a code like this?

(I know I could do this with Zapier but that would require ridiculous plan to have it done :))

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help:

It gets the latest csv file in a folder and loads it in to the active sheet.

```
function getTheLatestFile() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  const arr = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    arr.push({name:file.getName(),id:file.getId(),date:file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  arr.sort((a,b)=> {
    return new Date(b.date).valueOf() - new Date(a.date).valueOf();
  })
  let vs = Utilities.parseCsv(DriveApp.getFileById(arr[0].id),getBlob().getDataAsString());
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I modified it a bit to append data in the main sheet instead of deleting it and adding a new data, and also removed headers with .shift() functionality and got everything I need to automate it fully. Appreciated!

Comment: Cooper, I am trying to use this, but I get `Error. 
Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.` with two files in the folder Thanks

Comment: from `while(files.hasNext) {
    let file = files.next();
    arr.push({name:file.getName(),id:file.getId(),date:file.getDateCreated()});
    console.log(arr)
  }` the error occurs here `let file = files.next();`